# Minicom app for Android?

Tags: applications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, command-line

Is there a comm app similar to minicom, hyperterminal or zterm for Android? I would prefer a port of minicom, if it exits. BTW, I'm running Android ICS on a Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: What exactly do you want to communicate with? Telnet?SSH? Hardware serial devices? Local character-based software?

Comment: @Kevin: primarily hardware serial devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found one. There is an app called microcom that is part of some newer busybox packages. I used the latest busybox (1.9.3) that could be installed by BusyBox Pro (Steven Stericson) from the Android Market. I replaced busybox 1.9.3CM that came with my ROM and which did not have microcom.

With that busybox you just have to open a terminal (I used BTEP) and type microcom. The short help file will be displayed. Using it can be as simple as:

```
microcom -s 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I am still interested in a more full-featured version -- something more like minicom. But at least microcom gets the minimal job done for now.

If no one offers a more full featured app than microcom, I'll accept my answer in a few days.